# How to Solve an error due to floating value in bash?

Tags: bash

```
echo -n "x1 = "
echo -e "scale=3\n0.5*(-($B)+sqrt($D))/($A)" | bc
```

whats the meaning of -n , -e and bc?

suppose,

```
D=$(( ($B)*($B)-4*($A)*($C) ));
echo  D = $D
if [ $D -gt 0 ] ; then
then
    echo -n "x1 = "
    echo -e "scale=3\n0.5*(-($B)+sqrt($D))/($A)" | bc
    echo -n "x2 = "
    echo -e "scale=3\n0.5*(-($B)-sqrt($D))/($A)" | bc
fi
```

so whenever i give something floating type value . It shows errors.

Comment: You can start with `man echo`

Comment: Take a look at `help echo` and `man bc`.

Comment: `echo -n`: Do not output the trailing newline.
`echo -e`: Enable interpretation of the backslash-escaped characters in each STRING. Do a `man echo` for a full list for your version.
You're also piping (the `|` character) the output to `bc`, so familiarize yourself with those, too.  

As is, what is the error message you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are all available in the `man`-pages for `bash` and `bc` if you want to do more research.

---

Options for the `echo` built-in bash command include `-n` which prevents the output of a newline character following the output (so the the expression is on the same line as the literal `x1 =`, rather than on the following line).

The `-e` option allows it to interpret extended characters such as `\n` for a newline. This is actually unnecessary since `bc` understands semi-colons as separators as well, so you could have just used:

```
echo "scale=3; 0.5*(-($B)+sqrt($D))/($A)" | bc
```

In terms of the `bc`, this is the arbitrary-precision calculator included with most UNIX-like operating systems. The command above is treated as if you had started up `bc` and actually *typed in* the text `scale=3; 0.5*(-($B)+sqrt($D))/($A)`, with those `B`, `D` and `A` variables replaced with their actual values.

The `bc` program would interpret that then output the result.

---

As to the error you're getting with floating point values, it's because the line:

```
D=$(( ($B)*($B)-4*($A)*($C) ))
```

is being interpreted by `bash` and it, unlike `bc`, does not do calculations with floating point values - it's strictly integer only.

To solve this, just move the *full* calculation of the quadratic solutions into `bc`, something like:

```
echo -n 'x1='; echo "scale=3; (-$B + sqrt($B*$B - 4*$A*$C)) / (2*$A)" | bc
echo -n 'x2='; echo "scale=3; (-$B - sqrt($B*$B - 4*$A*$C)) / (2*$A)" | bc
```